# Conditional IF statement in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, azure

I have a SQL Database hosted in Azure along with my Web app (both in the same data center as well).

I have a *few similar LINQ queries which basically differ only in the* `.Where()` clause.

Since the queries are similar, I don't want to have to have code repition anywhere but I *don't think* LINQ allows me to have conditional IFs in the statements.

I've added a code snippet below, so any pointers on this would be helpful. I should also mention it's querying a View and not a table.

```
case Constants.OPENED:
    lstQueryEvents = db.tblEmailEvents
        .Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.OPENED_TYPE)
        .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.UserID == UserId)
        .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.blnOutlookRec == true || t.tblSentEmail.tblMerges.blnOutlookRec == true)
        .Where(s => s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(o => o.strEmailAddress.Contains(strSearch)) || s.tblSentEmail.strSubject.Contains(strSearch) || s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(r => r.strDisplayName.Contains(strSearch)))
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.dtmEvent)
        .Take(intNumRecords)
        .ToList();
    break;
case Constants.CLICKED:
    lstQueryEvents = db.tblEmailEvents
        .Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.CLICKED_TYPE)
        .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.UserID == UserId)
        .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.blnOutlookRec == true || t.tblSentEmail.tblMerges.blnOutlookRec == true)
        .Where(s => s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(o => o.strEmailAddress.Contains(strSearch)) || s.tblSentEmail.strSubject.Contains(strSearch) || s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(r => r.strDisplayName.Contains(strSearch)))
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.dtmEvent)
        .Take(intNumRecords)
        .ToList();
    break;
```

Comment: can `Constants.OPENED` and `Constants.OPENED_TYPE` be made the same (enum?) value? Same for clicked, clicked_type. Then whatever you're switching is what you need in the where clause. Or, write a method with a parameter that goes into the where clause. DRY.

Comment: @BenKnoble the `Constants.OPENED` and `Constants.OPENED_TYPE` aren't Enums, but they're just hard coded values (i.e. `Constants.OPENED` is the string literal `OPENED` and `Constants.OPENED_TYPE` is the string literal `O`. What exactly can I do?

Comment: Well, if they are the same const, then instead of doing `switch (someValue) case blah: break; case otherblah: break;` then you can do `query = source.Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == someValue)...`   See the power?

Comment: this would of course mean that whatever data uses one would have to switch to the other and that's likely not practical; i suggest the private helper method approach or either of those below.

Comment: @BenKnoble I'll use Marcin's answer below...I'll put the more "general" stuff outside of the switch and the specific stuff inside. At least it doesn't make the entire LINQ huge.

Answer (score 2):

You can create LINQ queries in multiple statements and unless you need the results (e.g. by calling `ToList`) it will not be executed. So you could do following:

```
var lstQueryEventsQuery = db.tblEmailEvents
        .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.UserID == UserId)
        .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.blnOutlookRec == true || t.tblSentEmail.tblMerges.blnOutlookRec == true)
        .Where(s => s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(o => o.strEmailAddress.Contains(strSearch)) || s.tblSentEmail.strSubject.Contains(strSearch) || s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(r => r.strDisplayName.Contains(strSearch)));

switch(yourVariable)
{
    case Constants.OPENED:
        lstQueryEventsQuery = lstQueryEventsQuery.Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.OPENED_TYPE)
        break;
    case Constants.CLICKED:
        lstQueryEventsQuery = lstQueryEventsQuery.Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.OPENED_TYPE)
        break;
}

lstQueryEvents = lstQueryEventsQuery.OrderByDescending(t => t.dtmEvent)
    .Take(intNumRecords)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ahh, I see..I can write up everything I want, and right before I exit my method I can execute it via `.ToList()` to retrieve the results thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split up the chain into separate calls like this:

```
var emailEvents = db.tblEmailEvents.AsQueryable();
switch(myConstant)
{
    case Constants.OPENED:
        emailEvents = emailEvents.Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.OPENED_TYPE;
    break;
    case Constants.CLICKED:
        emailEvents = emailEvents.Where(t => t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.CLICKED_TYPE;
    break;
    //etc
}

lstQueryEvents = emailEvents.Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.UserID == UserId)
    .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.blnOutlookRec == true || t.tblSentEmail.tblMerges.blnOutlookRec == true)
    .Where(s => s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(o => o.strEmailAddress.Contains(strSearch)) || s.tblSentEmail.strSubject.Contains(strSearch) || s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(r => r.strDisplayName.Contains(strSearch)))
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.dtmEvent)
    .Take(intNumRecords)
    .ToList();
```

This works because the result of each call returns `IEnumerable`, which isn't evaluated until you attempt to use it (or call `ToList`).

Comment: That will not work, because `emailEvents` will be inferred to be `DbSet<T>` and `Where` returns `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek you're right, thanks. Forgot the `AsQueryable`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Build a predicate based on your constant value. I guess you could also directly pass the predicate to your method as a parameter.

```
Func<T, bool> predicate;
switch(constant)
{
    case Constants.OPENED:
        predicate = (T t) => (t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.OPENED_TYPE);
        break;
    case Constants.CLICKED:
        predicate = (T t) => (t.strType.ToUpper() == Constants.CLICKED_TYPE);
        break;
}

lstQueryEvents = db.tblEmailEvents
    .Where(predicate)
    .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.UserID == UserId)
    .Where(t => t.tblSentEmail.blnOutlookRec == true || t.tblSentEmail.tblMerges.blnOutlookRec == true)
    .Where(s => s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(o => o.strEmailAddress.Contains(strSearch)) || s.tblSentEmail.strSubject.Contains(strSearch) || s.tblSentEmail.tblRecipients.Any(r => r.strDisplayName.Contains(strSearch)))
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.dtmEvent)
    .Take(intNumRecords)
    .ToList();
```